# Style select form

Tags: css, forms, html-select

I'm trying to give my select form a background-color and border but this doesn't seem to work.

This is my HTML:

```
<select class="size">
    <option>maat</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select.size {
    width: 170px;
    border: 2px solid #dcd8d7;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: `#ffffff` is for white color\, Are you sure, background is going to be white? Code is [working](http://jsfiddle.net/s65nc/)

Comment: Yes, however I'm getting this kind of standard white to grey gradient instead. And padding isn't working either.

Comment: Try changing different color coz currently it is working but in white color. http://jsbin.com/xemiyuba/2/

Comment: Yes but I want to get rid of the gradient and just have a solid background-color. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Change `background` to `background-color`

Also check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NQ5vb/

You have to set a different color than white(#FFFFFF). Take a look here [HTML Color Picker](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)

Comment: You can use `background` too!

Comment: As @Dhaval Marthak wrote you can use background too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this

```
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
    <option>Maat</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and the css is like this

```
.styled-select select {
   width: 170px;
   border: 2px solid #dcd8d7;
   border-radius: 4px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```